# Someone downvoting my questions

Tags: support, status-completed

I just noticed that somebody went through some of my recent questions and downvoted them silently.

I understand that my questions may not be the best on this site, but along with a downvote I usually expect some suggestions for improving the content.

This may just be some angry user, but anyway I'd like somebody to look into this.

Comment: Here in the meta search for the term "serial downvoting".

Comment: We'll take a look at this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The offending downvotes have been removed and your reputation has been restored. The user responsible has also been contacted to inform them of our voting policies. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.